# Sum multi columns in datagridview and add in footer

Tags: c#

This code works for me to sum one column in a datagridview, but I want to sum multiple columns in the datagridview

```
decimal sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < dgw.RowCount; i++)
{
    // we only sum the first and third column as an example
    sum1 += Convert.ToDecimal(dgw.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
    sum2 += Convert.ToDecimal(dgw.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
}

// add the total row
string[] totalrow = new string[] { sum1.ToString(), "", sum2.ToString() };
dgw.Rows.Add(totalrow);

// add a rowheadertitle
dgw.RowHeadersWidth = 60;
dgw.Rows[dgw.RowCount - 1].HeaderCell.Value = "Total";
```

Comment: What is the real problem ? multiple columns? that `for` do same , get col content by col index like what you have done.

Comment: i want sum more column in datagrideview these code work with me to sum one column i want to sum second column in datagrideview and add sum in footer gridview

Comment: Sum them as normal and at the end add the desired column sums together. Example: In the above code you are summing col1 and col3 in sum1 and sum3 respectively. So after the loop just add sum1 and sum3 to get total of col1 and col3 values.

Comment: Then, you can get second col value in your loop like `dgw.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by `dgw.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value` you can get all cell 2 value in your loop.

Try this:

```
.....
decimal sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0,sum3 = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < dgw.RowCount; i++)
{
    // we only sum the first and third column as an example
    sum1 += Convert.ToDecimal(dgw.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
    sum2 += Convert.ToDecimal(dgw.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
    sum3 += Convert.ToDecimal(dgw.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);//Second cell
}
// add the total row
string[] totalrow = new string[] { sum1.ToString(), "", sum2.ToString(),"", sum3.ToString() };
dgw.Rows.Add(totalrow);
.....
```